# How to connect "draggable" and "sortable" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to figure out how to connect `draggable` to `sortable` in jQuery. I also want the dragged div to snap to the other divs. Here is an example of what I want the jQuery to do:

```
<div id="yes">Drag me and you'll be able to drop divs into me.</div>
<div id="no">Drag me but you won't be able to drop divs into me.</div>
<div id="main">

</div>
```

After dragging the div with the id of "yes", the code will be like this:

```
<div id="yes">Drag me and you'll be able to drop divs into me.</div>
<div id="no">Drag me but you won't be able to drop divs into me.</div>
<div id="main">
     <div id="d1" class="droppable"></div>
</div>
```

Now if you'll drag one of the divs, the div that being dragged can enter to each div with the class of "droppable" (this class being added only if you drag the div from the div with the id of "yes".

Here is an example of what I want the code to look like after a lot of dragging:

```
<div id="yes">Drag me and you'll be able to drop divs into me.</div>
<div id="no">Drag me but you won't be able to drop divs into me.</div>
<div id="main">
     <div id="d1" class="droppable">
          <div id="d2" class="droppable"><div id="d6"></div></div>
     </div>
     <div id="d3" style="margin-top: 11px"></div>
     <div id="d4" style="margin-top: 34px;margin-right: 39px"></div>
     <div id="d5" class="droppable"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is, of course, just an a example of how the code can look after a lot of dragging.
The divs can be dropped only into the main div. The divs can be dragged after dropping too. The `style` with the `margin`s is by where you put the div - if it is exactly on the border of the father div, there will be no style. if you'll drop it in the middle of the box, the margin will be the location of the div...

**In conclusion, I want that if you drag a div from the div with the id of "yes", the div will be able to have a child div, but the div is being dragged from the div with the id "no", this div will never be a father div, and both of the divs will be snapping to other divs while dragging them. If div is being placed on top of a div but not inside of him (on the border), he will be snapped, but never be stayed on top of div. The divs will be "styled" with margins and not with `position: absolute`.**

Sorry about my bad English & thank you!

Comment: Something like this? https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/draggable/sortable.html

Comment: @Grim... thanks, but it is not exactly it, the only thing that is close to the thing I ask is that there is a div that you can drag from there. I'm asking that I'll be able to place a div everywhere I want it: on the middle of the page, at the top or even inside other.